# Wait for multiple responses then make another call

Tags: afnetworking

I have three API calls that I am making with AFNetworking 2.0. The first two are POST requests (/picture) to upload an image and the third request (/message) uses an identification number returned from both of those image POST calls responses.  Practically, there is a chance that the user could initiate the third request before I have a response from one of the /image POSTs. I don't want to block the UI.  I know AFNetworking is asynchronous and this seems like a synchronous process.  Looking for some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AFURLConnectionOperation` operation dependencies or batching, or `dispatch_group` to synchronize behavior once certain conditions are met. Alternatively, dependent calls can be nested into successive completion blocks.